# How do you store extra information of files stored in Cloud Storage for Firebase with Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to store some files in Firebase storage and when the user accesses or downloads those files, I want to show some extra information about each file (such as a description, date, etc). File metadata can only store name, size and contentType so where and how can I store the extra information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#adding-metadata), when uploading a file you can add some "custom metadata" via the [`SettableMetadata`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage_platform_interface/latest/firebase_storage_platform_interface/SettableMetadata-class.html) Class, as follows:

```
  // Create your custom metadata.
  firebase_storage.SettableMetadata metadata =
      firebase_storage.SettableMetadata(
        cacheControl: 'max-age=60',
        customMetadata: <String, String>{
          'userId': 'ABC123',
        },
      );

  try {
    // Pass metadata to any file upload method e.g putFile.
    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('uploads/file-to-upload.png')
        .putFile(file, metadata);
  } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom meta along with file in firebase storage like the other answer, or you could create a firestore document for it. Let me know if you need some sample code